# Onclick event not being covered on TEST - Jest Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, jestjs

I have the following test for onClick event, the test passes but its not being covered when I run npm test --coverage.

Using Jest - enzyme REACT JS

Any suggestions or solutions. Try to keep the same syntax
Thanks

here is the test file:

```
beforeEach(() => 
  wrapper = mount(<BrowserRouter><AddViewModal {...baseProps} /></BrowserRouter>));

it("should call blankRequestClick functions on button click", () => {
  baseProps.resetShapeDefinition.mockClear();
  baseProps.setRequestId.mockClear();
  wrapper.setProps({}); 
  wrapper.find('AddViewModal').setState({
     ViewName: 'test',
     RequestID: 'test',
     Requests: [  {Name:'test'},   ],
  }); 

 wrapper.find('#add-new-catalog').at(1).simulate("click");
 wrapper.find('.continue_button_div').at(1).simulate("click"); 
 wrapper.find('.continue_button_div').at(2).simulate("click"); 
 expect(baseProps.resetShapeDefinition).toHaveBeenCalled();
 expect(baseProps.setRequestId).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Here is the code:

```
   { this.state.ViewName !== '' && this.state.allowNext && (this.state.RequestID == '' || this.state.Requests.length == 0)?

          <Link id='add-new-catalog' to={{pathname: `${this.props.location.pathname.replace('home', 'Edit')}/1`}} style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
         <div  onClick={()=>{this.blankRequestClick()}} 
          className="continue_button_div">
          <button className='continue_button' id='continue-blank-add-new-view' title='Continue with Blank Request'  type='button'>
           Continue with Blank Request
           </button>
          </div>
          </Link> :
```

Goal is to make the test pass and click event gets called.

Comment: @skyboyer any ideas ?

Comment: you are calling `onClick` for `div#continue_button_div` while handler is set for button. you need calling(`simulate()` is just shortcut for `.props.onClick()` call) `onClick` right on `<button>`

Comment: How could i do that for example

Comment: wrapper.find('button').at(0).simulate("click");   ??

Comment: `wrapper.find('#cancel-add-new-view1').simulate("click");`

Comment: I have done that before as well and it couldnlt find it. I thought you had to specify button inside of wrapper.find(button...) something like that to work

Comment: there are different ways to [aim particular component](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/selector.html). using CSS-like `'#id'` notation also works. You may fail to find element if it is not rendered due to conditions around.

Comment: Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead. this is what i am getting so far

Comment: it means there is no such element rendered. check your `this.state.ViewName !== '' && this.state.allowNext && (this.state.RequestID == '' || this.state.Requests.length == 0)?`

Comment: The test is passing. I was able to figure the cancel one based on console.log. I ran npm coverage annd the click on blankrequest is not being covered.

Comment: console log: Here is the console log results :   <Link id="add-new-catalog" to={{...}} style={{...}} replace={false}>
                      <a id="add-new-catalog" style={{...}} onClick={[Function]} href="//1">
                        <div onClick={[Function: onClick]} className="continue_button_div">
                          <button className="continue_button" id="continue-blank-add-new-view" title="Continue with Blank Request" type="button">
                            Continue with Blank Request